# Prompt user for input using substitution variable

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g, plsql

```
DECLARE 
 localvar char;
BEGIN
 localvar := &ENUMBER;
 IF localvar ='A' then 
  dbms_output.put_line('Please proceed to Level1');
 ELSIF localvar='B' or localvar='C' then
  dbms_output.put_line('Please proceed to Level2');
 ELSIF localvar='D' then
  dbms_output.put_line('Please proceed to Level3');
 ELSE
  dbms_output.put_line('Invalid Entry');
 END IF;
END;
```

I am trying to prompt the user for input using a substitution variable in Oracle, but I am having a problem with this. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the user types `A`, the code will look like:

```
DECLARE 
 localvar char;
BEGIN
 localvar := A;
 IF localvar ='A' then 
  dbms_output.put_line('Please proceed to Level1');
 ELSIF localvar='B' or localvar='C' then
  dbms_output.put_line('Please proceed to Level2');
 ELSIF localvar='D' then
  dbms_output.put_line('Please proceed to Level3');
 ELSE
  dbms_output.put_line('Invalid Entry');
 END IF;
END;
/
```

Notice the line `localvar := A;`. This is obviously incorrect, as A is an unknown identifier.

Either type `'A'`, or put apostrophes in the code:

```
DECLARE 
 localvar char;
BEGIN
 localvar := '&ENUMBER';
 IF localvar ='A' then 
  dbms_output.put_line('Please proceed to Level1');
 ELSIF localvar='B' or localvar='C' then
  dbms_output.put_line('Please proceed to Level2');
 ELSIF localvar='D' then
  dbms_output.put_line('Please proceed to Level3');
 ELSE
  dbms_output.put_line('Invalid Entry');
 END IF;
END;
```

Comment: i am in office i will check after i get back home and try what you have mentioned and give a response sir.